# Gitlab continuous integration testing with Selenium

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a project to build, test and deploy an application to the cloud using a **.gitlab-ci.yml**

**1) Build the backend and frontend using pip install and npm install**

```
build_backend:
  image: python
  stage: build
  script:
  - pip install requirements.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - backend/

build_frontend:
  image: node
  stage: build
  script:
  - npm install
  - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend
```

**2) Run unit and functional tests using PyUnit and Python Selenium**

```
test_unit:
  image: python
  stage: test
  script:
    - python -m unittest discover

test_functional:
  image: python
  stage: test
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
  script:
    - python tests/example.py http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub https://$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG-dot-$GAE_PROJECT.appspot.com
```

**3) Deploy to Google Cloud using the sdk**

```
deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: https://$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG-dot-$GAE_PROJECT.appspot.com
  script:
    - echo $GAE_KEY > /tmp/gae_key.json
    - gcloud config set project $GAE_PROJECT
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/gae_key.json
    - gcloud --quiet app deploy --version $CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG --no-promote
  after_script:
    - rm /tmp/gae_key.json
```

This all runs perfectly, except for the selenium tests are run on the deployed url not the current build:

```
python tests/example.py http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub https://$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG-dot-$GAE_PROJECT.appspot.com
```

I need to have gitlab run three things simultaneously:
 a) Selenium
 b) Python server with the application
 - Test script

Possible approaches to run the python server:

- Run within the same terminal commands as the test script somehow
- Docker in Docker
- Service

Any advice, or answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am also trying to run selenium tests on Gitlab ci. Can you please let me know if you configured selenium tests to run in interactive mode or using headless browsers?

Comment: At the moment I've left selenium on its default configuration

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on how I set up [web tests for a php application](https://blog.johanv.org/posts/gitlab-ci-codeception-and-selenium-web-tests/). Ok PHP, but I guess something similar can be done for a python project.

What I did, was starting a php development server from within the container that runs the web tests. Because of the artifacts, the development server can access the php files. I figure out the IP address of the container, and using this IP address the selenium/standalone-chrome container can connect back to the development server.

I created a simple [demo-project](https://gitlab.com/johanv/codeception-ci-demo), you can check out the [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/johanv/codeception-ci-demo/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L37) file. Note that I pinned the selenium container to an old version; this was because of an issue with an old version of the php webdriver package, today this isn't needed anymore.

Comment: So essentially your solution is to run the php server in the background using "command &>/dev/null &" I would need to try that but that could work! https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/